# tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift5

I'm have this annoying problem. I've searched a lot. A lot of person suggested multiple things.
Like having these **TableViewDataSource** and **TableViewDelegate** added;

```
class SalesNewViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

connecting referencing outlets;

[image]

and connecting data source and delegate by code;

```
TableView.dataSource = self
TableView.delegate = self
```

I'm getting this error while trying to performSegue, without **performSegue** (Like if i want to print *hello* to console via clicking on *TableViewCell*) it doesnt give any error;

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "SalesSegue", sender: self)
}
```

And im using same thing for another View and it works without a problem. Any help would be really lovely.

**Edit 1:** I have two required methods up an running. **numberOfRowsInSection** and **cellForRowAt**

Answer (score 0):

If you search on "UITableViewDataSource" in the Xcode help system, you'll get the article on that protocol. It says:

```
Only two methods of this protocol are required, and they are shown in the following example code.

// Return the number of rows for the table.     
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return 0
}

// Provide a cell object for each row.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // Fetch a cell of the appropriate type.
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTypeIdentifier", for: indexPath)
   
   // Configure the cell’s contents.
   cell.textLabel!.text = "Cell text"
       
   return cell
}
```

You talk about connecting stuff, but you don't mention implementing those methods.

Assuming your view controller is your table view's data source, your view controller needs to implement at least those 2 methods (`numberOfRows(inSection:)` and `cellForRow(at:)`).

You can either have them in the body of your view controller, or in an extension that provides protocol conformance for the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

(Note that the apple-provided sample code for `numberOfRows(inSection:)` will cause your table view to be empty. You will need to replace the `return 0` bit with code that returns the number of rows in **your** table view, whatever that means in your app.)

Comment: My bad on not mentioning that i have those methods. In fact; i have them. Without **performSegue** function, there is no problem but when i try to do that, it gives me error.

Comment: You only get the error when tapping on the cell triggers a performSegue? Then it seems likely that the view controller that gets invoked by the segue is the one that's falling. Add breakpoints to the init method, viewDidLoad, and table view data source and delegate methods in the view controller that's invoked by the segue "SalesSegue"